# Google Map APIs : UK specific results

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a map application in Android. I'm using Google maps API to show results in Autocomplete textview dropdown .The results this API is returning is of the places of the entire world . I want to show results o provide solutions to places only of a particular country eg .UK
   How should I do it . Is there any specific flag to be set for it .

My URL : 
**private static String SUGGETION_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%s&types=geocode&sensor=true&key=xxxxx.xxx-xxxxx";**

Please suggest ways by which this url will return results to places only in UK ?

Comment: Found an incorrect way to do it by using Location biasing : http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#location_biasing .... but it still show area outside UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to force the API to restrict it's results to a region like you can in some of the other Google Maps Web Service APIs.  If you really need that functionality then maybe you should be using the [Geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) API or the [Places Autocomplete API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#places_autocomplete) as included in the Google Maps JS V3 API.

If you can't use either of those two suggestions your options are limited to:

1. You can use the location / radius [parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#location_biasing) like you found, but there are treated as more like "suggestions" than absolutes.
2. I'd try setting the language parameter to `en-GB` which might favor UK-based results slightly over others.